# C: Subtract arrays

Tags: arrays, c, subtraction

I have three arrays.

```
int Aarr[31];
int Barr[12];
int Carr[];
```

I want to substract every element from `Aarr` by every element from `Barr` and assign it to `Carr`.

```
for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
Carr[i]=Aarr[i]-Barr[i];
}
```

Since `Barr` has less integers in it that `Aarr` the subtraction is not correct.

How should I write this so that every time the code gets to the end of `Barr` it start from `Barr`'s start but `Aarr` continues from where it was?

Comment: with a nested for loop, also you should initiate `Carr` properly

Comment: Use the modulo operator? (`Barr[i % 12]`)

Comment: And by the way, since `A` only has 31 elements your loop condition should be `i<31`.

Comment: @Michael I didn't understand why `Barr[i % 12]` will work here, he wants every subtraction possible between both arrays

Comment: Give an example for input and output data

Answer (score 0):

For the following I'll adress simpler example.

So you want nested `for` loops one to iterate over `Aarr` and the second to iterate over `Barr` and just assign it to `Carr`.

The following do exactly that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Aarr[5] = {19, 10, 8, 17, 9};
    int Barr[2] = {1,3};
    int Carr[5*2];
    
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
            Carr[i * 2 + j] = Aarr[i] - Barr[j];
        }
    }
    for(int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
      printf("%d ", Carr[loop]);

    return 0;
}
```

And the print loop will give you:

```
18 16 9 7 7 5 16 14 8 6
```

Which is exactly the subraction of every element from `Aarr` by every element of `Barr`

Note the following:

1. You should have initialsed `Carr` to have size that is a multiplication of the sizes of both arrays.
2. If your array had `k` values you should iterate up until `k-1` since you start indexing from 0.